# I want to the sum of the 6th column vlaues

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception

The code:

```
import csv
cr = csv.reader(open("filename"))
next(cr)
print (sum(float(x[6]) for x in cr))
```

But getting an error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexError: list index out of range and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th column has an index of 5 rather than 6, so change:

```
print (sum(float(x[6]) for x in cr))
```

to:

```
print (sum(float(x[5]) for x in cr))
```

But if you are still getting `IndexError` after the change, it may be that some of the rows in your CSV do not have a 6th column, in which case you can add a condition to your generator expression to skip rows that do not have 6 columns:

```
print (sum(float(x[5]) for x in cr if len(x) >= 6))
```