# Line 7, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, youtube

Please help me fix this, this is my code which I've already tried.
I really appreciate your help.

```
import urllib.request
import re

search_keyword="ill%20wiat"
html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_keyword)
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])
```

Comment: check `video_ids` value to ensure it is not empty, or None,  you can do so by `print(video_ids)`

Comment: video_ids list has empty output (print (len(video_ids)). it doesn't have any element to access.
    if video_ids:
     print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])
    else:
     print ("Empty")

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: list index out of range and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-python)

Comment: Tejesh: **This question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check page you try to parse. you wrote:

```
r"watch?v=(\S{11})"
```

just remember that ? char here will be parsed as REGEX operator and not string you want,
so first of all you need to write it like:

```
/watch[?]v=(\S{11})
```

so your regex will be parsed properly
Second: good practice to print your list to see what you get and iterate via list using FOR loop instead of directly accessing index [0].
in you case you get this error just because your list of id is empty.

next code is working for me

```
import urllib.request
import re

search_keyword="ill%20wiat"
url="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+search_keyword
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   video_ids = re.findall("/watch[?]v=(\S{11})", response.read().decode())
   for video in video_ids:
      print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video)
```

P.S don't wrap your code with try/except to catch such thrown errors

Answer (score 0):

urlib won't give you data
use

```
import requests
html=requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+search_keyword)
text=html.text
```

text have all html data so search from text

Comment: but it returns the whole html code of youtube, how to get only the youtube url

Comment: use beautifulsoup for html parcing