# CSV file IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to process and get all spam messages from the ham/spam dataset and write it into another csv file. My code and the error received are here:

My code:

```
import csv
file = "spam.csv"
file2 = "data.csv"
with open(file, "r") as f:
    with open(file,"a") as f2:
        csvreader1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=",")
        for row in csvreader1:
            print(len(row))
            if "spam" in row[1]:
                writer.writerow([row[1],2])
```

Error received:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Email_classifier+ignition\E_mail_classifier\help.py", line 9, in <module>
  if "spam" in row[1]:
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Please help**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: list index out of range and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-python)

Comment: Can you give an example of your CSV file?

Comment: Your row variable doesn't have a value indexed 1.

Comment: `with open (file, "a") as f2` should be `with open(file2, "a")`. Also, I'd name `file` as `input_file` and `file2` as `output_file` to be a bir clearer. You also don't need the `delimeter=","` bits; that's the default. Consider using the `csv.DictReader` ... it'll make your life a lot easier, and probably clean up this bug. Bug is hard to pinpoint because we can't see the actual CSV your parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions, either you put the if condition in Try/Expect or add another if before your if condition:

```
try:
    if "spam" in row[1]:
        writer.writerow([row[1],2])
except Exception  as e:
    print(e)
```

Or:

```
if len(row) < 2:
    if "spam" in row[1]
    ...
```

Comment: import csv
file = "spam.csv"
file2 = "data.csv"
with open(file, "r") as f:
    with open(file,"a") as f2:
        csvreader1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=",")
        for row in csvreader1:
            try:
                if row:
                    if "spam" in row[0]:
                        writer.writerow([row[1:-1],2])

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        print("done")
                        this code didn't through any error but it simply do anything