# Watson caption converter IndexError: list out of range

Tags: python

I'm using [watson caption converter](https://github.com/kevinambrose/watson-caption-converter) and I'm getting an indexError list out of range while using jupyter notebook. Any way to fix this error?

Here is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c505fadd11ee> in <module>
131 
132             # formats time for SRT format
--> 133             st_time = format_time(x[2], "srt")
134             en_time = format_time(x[3], "srt")
135 

<ipython-input-2-c505fadd11ee> in format_time(time, format)
 15 # function to format time for SRT file
 16 def format_time(time, format):
---> 17     ms = (str(time).split("."))[1]
 18     sec = time
 19     min = sec / 60

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: probably see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-python?rq=1

Comment: Welcome @Kevin . Please do see https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Comment: @TejasShetty i know what an indexerror is, just don't know how to fix this one. It only occurred with a large audio file so I'm wondering if it's due to that somehow

Comment: ok Great. Can you let us know @Kevin the whole code that you actually ran ? It is hard to know with what you have presented here. for example I have no idea what `x` is. Include as much detail as you can.