# is there a way to resolve index out of bonds error (using geopandas)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas, sentinel

```
 SHAPE_PATH = os.path.join(".", "/home/sahil/", "mapa.geojson")

  area_gdf = gpd.read_file(SHAPE_PATH)
```

## Geometry of an entire area

```
   full_geometry = Geometry(area_gdf.geometry.values[0], crs=CRS.WGS84)
```

## Bounding box of a test sub-area

```
   test_bbox = Geometry(area_gdf.geometry.values[1], crs=CRS.WGS84).bbox

   area_gdf.plot(column="name");
```

> Error-
> index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: what does `len(area_gdf)` return,  it 1 then of course its out of bounds...  how many features in the geojson - probably only 1...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to access the N'th item mean that my list has less than N items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/does-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-when-trying-to-access-the-nth-item-m)

Comment: yes len(area_gdf) returns 1. Im not sure why this is not working

Comment: if length is 1,  then absolutely it's out of bounds error as lists / arrays are zero indexed.  `area_gdf.geometry.values[1]` is the 2nd value in array that has only 1 value

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example