# IndexError: list index out of range in python while using greater than operator

Tags: python

I'm checking if  the element in the first index  is greater than its corresponding element in the next index. if it is greater to be added into the new list.

Here is the code.

```
def solution(A):
    row1 = []
    for index in range(len(A)):
        if A[index] > A[index + 1]:
            row1.append(A[index])

    return row1


print(solution(A=[5, 4, 3, 6, 1]))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zeddy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/index.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(solution(A=[5, 4, 3, 6, 1]))
  File "/home/zeddy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/index.py", line 5, in solution
    if A[i] > A[i + 1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried using enumerate function but the same problem occurs
I'm expecting to get the a new list containing elements which are greater.

Comment: I think that `i + 1` will be out of range at the end. Did you mean: `for index in range(len(A)-1):`?

Comment: `i+1` is too large by 1 in the last iteration.

Comment: the line  ````for index in range(len(A)):```` creates the error. length of list is 5, but max index is only 4 since index starts with 0. it has to be ````for index in range(len(A)-1):````

Comment: It has nothing to do with the greater than operator.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098660/12095740). You are trying to reach the non-existing element.

```
A[index + 1]
```

in the last step of the iteration, you will get IndexError.
Use `range(len(A) - 1)` instead.